# Clojure Spec and "Couldn't satisfy such-that predicate after 100 tries..."

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Let's say you have a `::givee` and a `::giver`:

```
(s/def ::givee keyword?)
(s/def ::giver keyword?)
```

That form a `unq/gift-pair`:

```
(s/def :unq/gift-pair (s/keys :req-un [::givee ::giver]))
```

And then you have a `:unq/gift-history` which is a `vector` of `unq/gift-pair`:

```
(s/def :unq/gift-history (s/coll-of :unq/gift-pair :kind vector?))
```

Last, suppose you want to replace one of the `:unq/gift-pair` in the `vector`:

```
(defn set-gift-pair-in-gift-history [g-hist g-year g-pair]
  (assoc g-hist g-year g-pair))
(s/fdef set-gift-pair-in-gift-history
        :args (s/and (s/cat :g-hist :unq/gift-history
                            :g-year int?
                            :g-pair :unq/gift-pair)
                     #(< (:g-year %) (count (:g-hist %)))
                     #(> (:g-year %) -1))
        :ret :unq/gift-history)
```

All works fine:

```
(s/conform :unq/gift-history
           (set-gift-pair-in-gift-history [{:givee :me, :giver :you} {:givee :him, :giver :her}] 1 {:givee :dog, :giver :cat}))
=> [{:givee :me, :giver :you} {:givee :dog, :giver :cat}]
```

Until I try to`stest/check` it:

```
(stest/check `set-gift-pair-in-gift-history)
             clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Couldn't satisfy such-that predicate after 100 tries.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Couldn't satisfy such-that predicate after 100 tries. {}
```

I have tried using `s/int-in` to limit the vector count (thinking that may be the problem) without success.

Any ideas on how to run `` (stest/check `set-gift-pair-in-gift-history) `` correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the generators for the vector and the index into the collection are independent/unrelated. The random vectors and integers aren't satisfying these criteria:

```
#(< (:g-year %) (count (:g-hist %)))
#(> (:g-year %) -1)
```

To `check` this function you can supply a custom generator that will generate the random `:unq/gift-history` vector, and build another generator for the index based on the size of that vector:

```
(s/fdef set-gift-pair-in-gift-history
  :args (s/with-gen
          (s/and
            (s/cat :g-hist :unq/gift-history
                   :g-year int?
                   :g-pair :unq/gift-pair)
            #(< (:g-year %) (count (:g-hist %)))
            #(> (:g-year %) -1))
          #(gen/let [hist (s/gen :unq/gift-history)
                     year (gen/large-integer* {:min 0 :max (max 0 (dec (count hist)))})
                     pair (s/gen :unq/gift-pair)]
             [hist year pair]))
  :ret :unq/gift-history)
```

This is using test.check's `let` macro, which is a convenience over `bind`/`fmap` that allows you to combine/compose generators using code that looks like a regular `let`. The custom generator returns a vector of arguments to the function.

Comment: Thank you Taylor. Success! This is the third time you've helped me with a Spec question. Can I meet you in the Loop to buy you a beer? Coffee/donut? :-)

Comment: Haha I’ll take all three, ping me :)

Comment: Sure - just tell me how? Checked here, your blog, GitHub and Chicago Clojure for an email? :-) Eric Tobin